# orders for what the Combat Report calls the “sickness and exhaustion

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Sheeran was there following orders for what the Combat Report calls the “sickness and exhaustion that had developed among the troops” in the “ fatiguing and heart-breaking fighting over rough terrain" in the drive from Salerno north to Venafro.

Does that mean he was following orders concerning sinckness and exhaustion among them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a particularly well-written phrase, and it reads confusingly especially with no context.

If Sheeran is, say, a doctor or someone else tasked with helping relieve the "sickness and exhaustion" then his orders might be something like ensuring their schedule or workload was changed to reduce these. He might have been ordered to also get them medicine, etc.

It could alternatively be read that his orders required the "...fighting over rough terrain" that resulted in the sickness and exhaustion. But with no context, I expect it's the first suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. He served as a rifleman.  Here's what I'm reading https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=YE6YDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=Sheeran+was+there+following+order+for+what+the+combat+reports+calls+sickness&source=bl&ots=KJPcNg7-3W&sig=ACfU3U2iVVGvbTojWygKu4-m9cnbZhjpNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJl-GTq87nAhWSHKYKHXvCAzQQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Sheeran was there following order for what the combat reports calls sickness&f=false